# ASP: Get Computer name and User based on IP from DHCP server

Tags: security, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

I have a windows 2008 network running Windows DHCP server on the domain controller "mydomainserver.mydomain.com".  I'm creating an intranet on that network, and I need to be able to find out the user name and computer name of the client computer for security reasons.

Users are NOT logging into this site, and users are using anything from IE to Firefox to Chrome.  The only information I have is their local IP Address.  I would like to be able to use the IP Address and query the DHCP server/domain controller to find out the Computer name, then use that to find out the current active user logged into that computer.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the IP of the machine, you can use WMI to query for the computer name:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_BIOS")

For Each objItem in colItems
    response.write objItem.Path_.Server
Next
```

This works on your local machine, but **it won't work querying remote machines for security reasons**. You may need to create a COM object using VB and give it high privileges to access remote machines.

Comment: Thanks, the IIS user this is running on has Administrator privileges on the local network, so it works.  Is there a way to use this to get the active username on that computer as well?

Comment: You can get pretty much all with WMI. A quick search for `active username using WMI`: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/03/04/how-to-get-the-logged-on-user-with-wmi-vbscript.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I used objItem.UserName to get the currently logged in user.  I was trying objItem.Path_.Server for some weird reason...